# How can I create maven module from 2 different parents?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, module

I'm adding new maven module to project. It will use spring-boot. Old modules are not using it. So, my new module must be child of parent project but at the same time must be a child of spring-boot-starter-parent. How can I make my project child of 2 different parent?

My current parent

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.somegroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
```

Spring-boot parent

```
<parent>
    <!-- Your own application should inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent -->
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: Can you past a single diagram of your Maven modules? What you have vs What you expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Maven project can have only one parent you can use a different approach. Instead of inheritance, you can import `spring-boot-dependencies` in the dependency management section and keep the original parent.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.somegroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

You can read about the constraints in [the official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent), which are basically about the way you change the version of dependencies provided by Spring Boot.

Comment: Ok, this is the solution. Actually it has some constraints but I will accept this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define another parent that sits between spring-boot and your own modules, and example is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
    <artifactId>myparent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
        <module>module2</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

Comment: If your child is a single module project yes.  What is in the parent that you currently have?

Comment: I have more than 8 childs in my parent

Comment: @FurkanYavuz just make your existing parent have spring boot as a parent.